# How would you simplify $(1/(4+3\sqrt2)) - (1/(\sqrt2 + 2))$ to the form of $1/(a+b\sqrt2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you simplify

$$\frac1{4+3\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2+2}$$

to the form of

$$\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}\;?$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: First put everything over a common denominator and do the arithemtic:

$$\frac1{4+3\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2+2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt2}{7+5\sqrt2}\;.$$

Then rationalize the denominator; when you’ve done that, you should have an expression of the form $k+\ell\sqrt2$. You want to write this in the form $$\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}\;,$$ so you want to solve

$$k+\ell\sqrt2=\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}$$

for $a$ and $b$. Rewrite it as

$$(k+\ell\sqrt2)(a+b\sqrt2)=1\;,$$

multiply it out, and get a system of two equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$. Then solve the system.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rationalize both fractions, by multiplying numerator and denominator of the first by $4 - 3\sqrt{2}$ and the second by $2 - \sqrt{2}$.
Thus write the expression in the form $c + d \sqrt{2}$. Then rationalize
$1/(c + d \sqrt{2})$ to get $a + b \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

First step:
$$
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
z=\frac{xy}{y-x}
$$
so you want to compute
$$
\frac{(4+3\sqrt{2})(2+\sqrt{2})}{2+\sqrt{2}-4-3\sqrt{2}}=
\frac{8+6\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2}+6}{-2-2\sqrt{2}}=
-\frac{7+5\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}=
-\frac{(7+5\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)}{(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)}
$$
and you're almost finished.